# Help with AppleScript cURL file upload

Tags: file-upload, curl, applescript

This is a sample CURL, which is what I am using to try and achieve an automatic upload of a file.

```
curl http://testflightapp.com/api/builds.json 
  -F file=@testflightapp.ipa 
  -F api_token='your_api_token' 
  -F team_token='your_team_token' 
  -F notes='This build was uploaded via the upload API' 
  -F notify=True 
  -F distribution_lists='Internal, QA'
```

I have made an AppleScript that asks for "notes", the file and whether to notify:

```
property api_token : "SECRET"
property team_token : "SECRET"
property notify : "False"
property pathToIPA : ""
property whats_new : ""

set whats_new_prompt to (display dialog "What's new in this version?" default answer "")
set whats_new to text returned of whats_new_prompt

set pathToIPA to (choose file with prompt "Select IPA")

set pathToIPA to (pathToIPA as text)

set notify_question to display dialog "Notify testers?" buttons {"No", "Yes"} default button 2
set notify_answer to button returned of notify_question

if notify_answer is equal to "No" then
    set notify to "False"
end if

if notify_answer is equal to "Yes" then
    set notify to "True"
end if

uploadIPA(api_token, team_token, notify, whats_new, pathToIPA)

on uploadIPA(api_token, team_token, notify, whats_new, pathToIPA)
    set TestFlightAPIUploadScript to "/usr/bin/curl" & ¬
        " http://testflightapp.com/api/builds.json " & ¬
        " –F " & "file=" & pathToIPA & ¬
        " –F " & "api_token=" & api_token & ¬
        " –F " & "team_token=" & team_token & ¬
        " –F " & "notes=" & whats_new & ¬
        " –F " & "notify=" & notify

    set UploadResponse to do shell script TestFlightAPIUploadScript
    return UploadResponse
    if UploadResponse contains "Status: 200 OK" then
        return "Success!"
    else
        return "Failure!"
    end if
end uploadIPA
```

Where I seem to have problems is with the file location. I am not sure, but I think it's returning the wrong format with : instead of / for the path.

Thanks in advance for any advice.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

To get a POSIX path of the form `/Users/you/file` instead of the classic Mac style path of `Macintosh HD:Users:you:file`, you can use `POSIX path of`: `set pathToIPA to POSIX path of pathToIPA`.  However, there are a couple of other things you should fix, in order of importance.

1. Use `quoted form of` for any user input which goes to the shell.  Otherwise, if the user writes `It's good.`, the shell will see the literal `'`.  Worse, someone could write `; rm -rf ~`, and then you'd be hosed.
2. You don't need a `property` for every variable; they're really for constants.
3. You're inconsistent with your naming.  It'd be nice to just see `these_vars`, `theseVars`, or `TheseVars`, not all three.  A rather minor point, though.  A similarly minor point is that you can remove some extra variables, though this is again a style point.
4. I don't know which you meant to have, but right *after* `return UploadResponse`, you have more code.  That code won't run, because you just returned.  Make sure you only leave one of those code paths!

You need to do #1; the other three things are definitely optional.  Even so, this is how I'd rewrite the code:

```
property api_token : "SECRET"
property team_token : "SECRET"

set whats_new to text returned of ¬
    (display dialog "What's new in this version?" default answer "")
set path_to_IPA to POSIX path of (choose file with prompt "Select IPA")
set notify_answer to button returned of ¬
    (display dialog "Notify testers?" buttons {"No", "Yes"} default button 2)
if notify_answer is equal to "No" then
    set notify to "False"
else if notify_answer is equal to "Yes" then
    set notify to "True"
else
    error "\"Notify testers\" check failed."
end if

upload_IPA(api_token, team_token, notify, whats_new, path_to_IPA)

on upload_IPA(api_token, team_token, notify, whats_new, path_to_IPA)
    set test_flight_API_upload_script to "/usr/bin/curl" & ¬
        " http://testflightapp.com/api/builds.json" & ¬
        -- add `@` to refer to the file itself not its path
        " -F " & "file=@" & quoted form of path_to_IPA & ¬ 
        " -F " & "api_token=" & quoted form of api_token & ¬
        " -F " & "team_token=" & quoted form of team_token & ¬
        " -F " & "notes=" & quoted form of whats_new & ¬
        " -F " & "notify=" & quoted form of notify

    set upload_response to do shell script test_flight_API_upload_script
    return upload_response
    -- Delete the above line or this if
    if upload_response contains "Status: 200 OK" then
        return "Success!"
    else
        return "Failure!"
    end if
end upload_IPA
```

Comment: Thanks for all the information and the revised script. It appears to work initially, but nothing is being uploaded. All I end up seeing the results output is the entire script, which now looks correct. I am not being returned any errors this time. Is it stopping prematurely? Thanks again for all your help.

Comment: @Canada: Oops, that's my fault.  I couldn't run the shell script, of course, so I told it to `return test_flight_API_upload_script` as the only way I could check the result, but (of course) *you* don't want that :-)  That's edited out now.

Comment: Ah, great. Hehe, sorry, I'm a total AppleScript beginner!

Comment: Hmm, still doesn't work :( Just returns an AS error with "% Total    % Received % Xferd  Average Speed   Time    Time     Time  Current
                                 Dload  Upload   Total   Spent    Left  Speed

  0     0    0     0    0     0      0      0 --:--:-- --:--:-- --:--:--     0
  0     0    0     0    0     0      0      0 --:--:-- --:--:-- --:--:--     0
 curl: (6) Couldn't resolve host '–F'

curl: (6) Couldn't resolve host 'file='

curl: (6) Couldn't resolve host '–F' "etc...

Comment: @Canada: Huh.  The problem is that the dashes in your original script, which ended up in mine via copy-paste, aren't ASCII dashes, but are Unicode en-dashes (character U+2013, decimal 8211).  Since those can't introduce an option, `curl` thinks they're a domain name, and then gets very confused.  Changing them to real ASCII dashes works fine (I got `You must supply api_token, team_token, the file and notes`).  I edited the answer to contain ASCII dashes, or you can just replace them on the five lines where you need to.

Comment: @Antal Fantastic answer! This might be an obvious tip but I always begin by running the cURL command via the command line, and then try to replicate that via Applescript - works for me anyway!

Comment: Thanks so much @Antal! One last note: It should be "file=@", otherwise it won't work, but it now finally works! Awesome!

Comment: Great advice, I'm looking at `curl` to upload files because I need to know the folder structure, something unavailable in the web browser.

Comment: Nice on the POSIX path part!